# Eclipse Scala IDE - class file needed by X is missing

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin

The Eclipse Scala plugin sometimes gives me bogus compilation errors saying "class file needed by *some class* is missing". This may be related to the fact that my project depends on other projects in the same workspace. Cleaning the project - even cleaning all open projects - does not resolve these errors. How can I make them go away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be caused by having two different versions of the same jar in the classpath (or, I suppose, by having just an old binary-incompatible version of a jar in the classpath). You can use a classpath checking tool like JBoss Tattletale to detect problems like this.

Here is an example Tattletale command line for analysing a project where all the jars are in the `lib` subdirectory:

```
java -Xmx512m -jar $HOME/opened/tattletale-1.1.2.Final/tattletale.jar $HOME/$PROJECT/lib $HOME/opened/tattletale-1.1.2.Final/reports/$PROJECT
```

Tattletale will create the report directory (the last argument) if it does not already exist. There are also versions of Tattletale for Maven and Ant projects.

Then open the file

```
tattletale-1.1.2.Final/reports/$PROJECT/index.html
```

in your web browser, and look around, particularly at pages like "Eliminate Jar files with different versions" and "Multiple jar files". Those pages will be empty if no problems of that type have been found.

Comment: IMO this is the most helpful answer, at least it have led me to resolution. I guess you should accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Close all open projects, then open the project that has these error(s). This worked for me, but only in some cases. It's possible that the project clean I did beforehand was needed as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Scala compiler appears to canonicalise paths (or maybe it's just the Play 1 Scala plugin, I'm not sure). So if you have created a symbolic link on Linux or Mac OS X, which points from `foo.jar` to `foo.jar.orig`, the Scala compiler will consider it to not be a `.jar` file, because it will look at the canonical path. So any jar like this will be silently dropped from your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

You may NOT have some required symbols in classpath, or, as well (!), you may have multiple versions of a jar in classpath, which was my case.

I had a similar problem while doing full rebuild in IntelliJ after mounting salat and casbah into the project. SBT builds went okay, while idea started to fail.

I've dismounted casbah, as it is transitively imported by salat and the problem vanished.

Hope that helps someone out there.