# spark - scala init error on build

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-ide

I'm trying to use spark in my scala application.

this is my spark dependency I'm using :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then in my code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
```

There is no error in my eclipse IDE, But code build (`mvn package exec:java`) is failed with the following error:

```
error: class file needed by SparkConf is missing.
[ERROR] reference type Cloneable of package scala refers to nonexisting symbol.
[ERROR] val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
[ERROR]                     ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: @om-nom-nom I don't think its a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033138/eclipse-scala-ide-class-file-needed-by-x-is-missing - saw this post and it doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: looks like some Scala version mismatch. Are you using 2.10.x? (In particular 2.10.4, as 2.10.3 has some issues with sbt)

Comment: yes - this was the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @massag has mention, It was a Scala version mismatch:

spark-core_2.10 is using scala 2.10.x