# building scala by maven error

Tags: scala, maven

pom is here:
https://github.com/leocook/spark-ml/blob/master/spark_ml/pom.xml

and

scala code is

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val line = sc.textFile(args(0))

line.flatMap(_.split(" ")).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).collect().foreach(println)

sc.stop()
```

when i build project,error message is:
[image]

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303314/spark-scala-init-error-on-build

Comment: You seem to be mixing different Scala versions (2.7.0 and 2.10.4), carefully look at the warnings. Please don't post screenshots, but copy & paste the text of the error message.

Comment: yes, it seems that you are requiring scala 2.7.0 and some libs require 2.10 (scala 2.7 is way too old, anything previous to 2.10 should be migrated)

Comment: Dear all, thank you very much! :-D

Answer (score 1):

There are to problems:

- `scala.Cloneable` not found, which means your Scala library is not setup properly.
- as mentioned in comments, you are mixing `2.7.0` and `2.10.4` scala versions.

You may want to inspect why the different versions are appearing using `mvn dependency:tree`, you will following output:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ ML ---
[INFO] org.leocook.spark:ML:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:jar:1.3.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill_2.10:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.21:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm:jar:shaded:1.07:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.6-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-i18n:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26.cloudera.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.10:jar:1.3.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.10:jar:1.3.0-cdh5.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.roaringbitmap:RoaringBitmap:jar:0.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-remote_2.10:jar:2.2.3-shaded-protobuf:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-actor_2.10:jar:2.2.3-shaded-protobuf:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.spark-project.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.1-shaded:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.uncommons.maths:uncommons-maths:jar:1.2.2a:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.spark-project.akka:akka-slf4j_2.10:jar:2.2.3-shaded-protobuf:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.10:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.10:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.10:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.scala-lang:scalap:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.mesos:mesos:jar:shaded-protobuf:0.21.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.23.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.tachyonproject:tachyon-client:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.tachyonproject:tachyon:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.spark-project:pyrolite:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.py4j:py4j:jar:0.8.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.4:test
[INFO] \- org.specs:specs:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO]    +- org.scalatest:scalatest:jar:0.9.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.scalacheck:scalacheck:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    \- org.jmock:jmock:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO]       +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]       \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.1:test
```

Comment: when I change <scala.version>2.7.0</scala.version> to <scala.version>2.10.0</scala.version>,it works! spark-core_2.10 is using scala 2.10.x

Comment: Alright, overriding the Scala version works for you. Cool!